# sudo regex: parse command arguments

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sudo, aix

I'm editing sudoers and would like to enable some command with arguments. These commands can be written with or without arguments. Example what I would like to enable:

```
rm -rf /app/*
rm /app/*
```

In my regex works only

```
'rm [-rf]?.*'
```

But I would like to have regex like this:

```
rm\s[-rf]\s\/app\/.*
```

Where **\s** is substitute for spaces.

Can I ask you for help with this nut? :]

Comment: Now I tried: `rm[[:space:]]*[-rf]?[[:space:]]*\/app\/.*` but it takes only second command without _-rf_.

Comment: Put `-rf` in between parenthesis: `(-rf)?`. Brackets are for character class.

Comment: @Ibarros: You're right! Now it is working... thank you. ;]

Comment: @Ibarros: Do you know how to replace (-rf) for another expression? Because SUDO doesn't support parenthesis.

Comment: What is the exact comand you are trying to execute?

Comment: In dir `/app` I have many dirs and files owned by different users. I'm trying to create SUDO command for `rm /app/somefile` and `rm -rf /app/somedir`.

Comment: I know that `rm -rf /app/*` is enaugh but I would like to know how to write it more precise and understand how it works. :]

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: Here is list of allowed wildcards in  [SUDO](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers). Only what is allowd is `?` Matches any single character, `[...]` Matches any character in the specified range, `[!...]` Matches any character not in the specified range and `*` Matches any set of zero or more characters.

Comment: I think if you allow the argument in sudoers, it will also allow the command to be executed without it, so no need to use the optional wildcard.

Comment: I just verified it and it doesn't work. If you have `rm -rf /app/*` in sudoers you cannot use `rm /app/file`.

Comment: You could do something like `[-]?[r]?[f]?`, but it will allow `-f` or `-r` also.

Comment: I tried this before and doesn't work. I see there is no way how to make it through regex. Many thx for your help Ibarros.